# Necesito buscar en base de datos dependiendo de los checkbox selecionados de las regiones, sus estados como lo podria resolver

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, ajax

tabla=`commerc` campos `id, name, brand, region, district, provincia, categoria`

Necesito que al consultar las regiones, me traiga los registros y se pueda seleccionar a través de un checkbox los distritos y las provincias de las regiones seleccionados.

**¿Como seria la llamada a mi base de datos?**

```
$consulta_estados_visa = $con->query(
    "SELECT commerce_id, commerce_region, commerce_brand 
     FROM commerc 
     WHERE commerce_brand = 'visa' 
     GROUP BY commerce_region"
);
```

Este es mi código de llamada a la base de datos.
Así me traigo los registro de regiones

```
<?php while($row = $consulta_estados_visa->fetch_assoc()) { ?>
<label class="list d-flex">
    <?php echo $row['commerce_region'] ?>
    <input type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $row['commerce_id'] ?>" name="estado[]"
    />
</label>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Muestra como están organizadas las tablas para poderte ayudar con la consulta, que es lo que quieres saber según parece, aunque no es del todo claro. Sería cuestión de hacer una consulta uniendo las tablas de `regiones`  y `estados` mediante `JOIN`.

Comment: @A.Cedano es una sola tabla con varios campos

Comment: @A.Cedano una tabla llamada commerc y tiene ocho registros son: ID, name, address, brand , region, provincia, district, category;;;; en mi primera consulta me traigo solos las region y de eso tengo que selecionar varias regiones dependiendo de lo que seleccione tengo que buscar en district y provincia

Comment: Por favor, [edita la pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/207430/edit) colocando en ella la información completa de las tablas, cómo se relacionan entre sí y el resultado que esperas obtener. Nada de eso queda claro en la pregunta ni se puede explicar en un simple comentario. Gracias.

Comment: Iván la pregunta todavía no es clara. ¿Hay más tablas?  ¿Cuáles son esas tablas, que campos tienen y cómo se relacionan entre sí?